# Invalid text in search box doesn't hit the Else statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, html

Aspx Engine

When I enter an invalid User Id in the text box and  hit search, "No Class found" is suppose to be displayed. Now "Search Result" is displayed.  It seems not to be hitting the else statement.

**html**

```
<div align="center">
    <form id="searchUser" method="post" action="Search">
        <table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td class="label">
            Enter ID:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="UserId" id="UserId" value="<%=(string)(ViewBag.userid)%>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
      <tr style ="display:none;">
        <td class="label">
            Email:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="Email" id="Text1" value="<%=(string)(ViewBag.email)%>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
      <tr style ="display:none;">
        <td class="label">
            lastFourDigits:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="LastFourDigits" id="Text2" value="<%=(string)(ViewBag.lastFourDigits)%>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button class="searchButton" id="searchButton">Search</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 </form>
  </div>
  <hr /> 

  <% if (ViewBag.searchClass !=null)
    { %>
    <h2>Search Resuls</h2>
    <br />
    <%List<AAlexUsers.Models.SearchClass> searchClassList= ViewBag.searchClass;%>
    <%if(searchClassList.Count>0)
    <table>
          <%foreach (AAlexUsers.Models.SearchClass searchClass in searchClassList)
     {%>
      <tr>
         <td>
            UserID:
        </td>
        <td class="content">
          <%=searchClass.userId%>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Email:
        </td>
        <td class="content">
         <%=searchClass.email%>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        Last Four Digits:
        </td>
        <td class="content">
          <%=searchClass.lastFourdigits%>
         </td>
    </tr>
    <%} %>
    <%} %>
 </table>

    <%} else %>
 <%{ %>
    <h2>No Class found.</h2>
 <%} %>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Search()
{
    string userId = Request["UserId"];
    string email = Request["Email"] ?? string.Empty;
    string lastFourdigits = Request["LastFourDigits"] ?? string.Empty;

    bool view = false;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
    {
        view = true;
    }
    if (!view)
    {
        List<AAlexUsers.Models.SearchClass> searchClass = 
            AAlexUsers.Models.SearchClass.Users(userId,email,lastFourdigits);
        {
            ViewBag.searchClass = searchClass;
            ViewBag.lastFourdigits = lastFourdigits;
            ViewBag.userId = userId;
            ViewBag.email = email;
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

**Model**

```
public class SearchClass
{
    public string userId { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string lastFourdigits { get; set; }

    public static List<AAlexUsers.Models.SearchClass> 
        Users(string userId, string email, string lastFourdigits)   
    {
        SearchClass Alex = new SearchClass();
        Alex.userId = "1234";
        Alex.email = "Alex@gmail.com";
        Alex.lastFourdigits = "1885";

        SearchClass Emilio = new SearchClass();
        Emilio.userId = "0928";
        Emilio.email = "Cubano@gmail.com";
        Emilio.lastFourdigits = "0706";

        SearchClass Ulysses = new SearchClass();
        Ulysses.userId = "0914";
        Ulysses.email = "lysses@gmail.com";
        Ulysses.lastFourdigits = "01zx";

        var list = new List<SearchClass>();
        list.Add(Alex);
        list.Add(Emilio);
        list.Add(Ulysses);


        IEnumerable<SearchClass> result = list;
        if (!string.Empty.Equals(userId))
            result = result.Where(u => u.userId == userId);

        return result.ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in your controller you are creating a searchClass:

```
List<AAlexUsers.Models.SearchClass> searchClass = AAlexUsers.Models.SearchClass.Users(userId,email,lastFourdigits);
```

In your Users(...) method you the following line *always* returns a List that is not null.

```
result = result.Where(u => u.userId == userId);

return result.ToList();
```

In the case that result is null, result.ToList() will return a List with 0 items in it.
Once you've received your List, you are then assigning it on this line in your controller:

```
ViewBag.searchClass = searchClass;
```

Once in your view, you are checking for:

```
<% if (ViewBag.searchClass !=null)
```

which will always be true since you return an empty List.

If you want to see if the proper result was returned, based on your posted code, you should not rely only on if the list is null.  Instead you should do this:

```
<% if (ViewBag.searchClass !=null && ViewBag.searchClass.Count > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have this code:

public ActionResult Search()
{
    string userId = Request["UserId"];
    string email = Request["Email"] ?? string.Empty;
    string lastFourdigits = Request["LastFourDigits"] ?? string.Empty;

```
bool view = false;

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
{
    view = true;
}
if (!view)
{
    List<AAlexUsers.Models.SearchClass> searchClass = 
        AAlexUsers.Models.SearchClass.Users(userId,email,lastFourdigits);
    {
        ViewBag.searchClass = searchClass;
        ViewBag.lastFourdigits = lastFourdigits;
        ViewBag.userId = userId;
        ViewBag.email = email;
    }
}
return View();
```

}

for the controller. You say you enter an invalid user, which  means there is a username entered, so since userId is not null or empty, view will be "false".

Since we take the opposite of view, that gives us true and then executes the code that gets a list of SearchClass objects that is returned by the Users method. Now, depending on what the return of Users is (it isn't given), you may be return an empty list (new List()) instead of null, which means that when you set searchClass to the ViewBag.searchClass, you will never be setting it to null.